# Pandas Dataframe: limit the number of rows with a common subset value

Tags: python, pandas

I have this data set (outputted in a .csv file):

```
email, link
0,,
1, hello@dog.com, dog.com
2, bark@dog.com, dog.com
3, growl@dog.com, dog.com
4, meow@cat.net, cat.net
5, purr@cat.net, cat.net,
6, sleep@cat.net, cat.net
7, scream@monkey.eu, monkey.eu
8, run@horse.com, horse.com
```

As you can see, some links are the same while the email is always unique. I would like to keep maximum 2 rows with the same link, removing the third and the subsequents, like this:

```
email, link
0,,
1, hello@dog.com, dog.com
2, bark@dog.com, dog.com
3, meow@cat.net, cat.net
4, purr@cat.net, cat.net,
5, scream@monkey.eu, monkey.eu
6, run@horse.com, horse.com
```

How to do it? I tried with this solution, but it only outputs the links. Merging it with the email address mess everythingup because of the different lenght of the subsets (lists):

```
from collections import Counter

def keep_n_dupes(remove_from, how_many):
    counts = Counter()
    for item in remove_from:
        counts[item] += 1
        if counts[item] <= how_many:
            yield item
new_links = list(keep_n_dupes(df['link'], 2))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`groupby.head`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html):

```
df.groupby('link').head(2)

          email         link
0     hello@dog.com    dog.com
1      bark@dog.com    dog.com
3      meow@cat.net    cat.net
4      purr@cat.net    cat.net
6  scream@monkey.eu  monkey.eu
7     run@horse.com  horse.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is using `nth`

```
df.groupby('link', as_index=False).nth([0,1])

Out[587]:
               email        link
1      hello@dog.com     dog.com
2       bark@dog.com     dog.com
4       meow@cat.net     cat.net
5       purr@cat.net     cat.net
7   scream@monkey.eu   monkey.eu
8      run@horse.com   horse.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas has groupby feature

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('path to the file')
df.groupby('link').head(2)
```

The above commands will group the links and will print the first 2 rows with the same link